# Webpack 4 configuration.module has an unknown property 'resolve'

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I am currently modifying a webpack config and have decided to put an alias in the config

The version of webpack i'm using is 4.19.1

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
      assets: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
    },
  },
```

I have required the path, tried making the path both relative and absolute both of which has had made no difference and I recieve the following error.

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.


- configuration.module has an unknown property 'resolve'. These properties are valid:
```

I did console log to see if the function exists and it does and am running out of ideas on what might be causing this.

Comment: have you read the error message? The configuration is wrong.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: @PlayMa256 Ah... Rookie mistake lol... -_- I encapsulated the "resolve" within the "module". Moved outside now it works thanks :)

Comment: @PlayMa256 classic helpful stackoverflow user. thanks for being a great representation of the programming community